# How to make a query with query builder in three tables?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, builder

I have three tables employe, skills and technologies 
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otJt3.png)

```
=====================
|    employe        |
=====================
|id_employe         |
|name               |
|id_skill           |


=====================
|    skills         |
=====================
|id_skill           |
|Id_technologie     |
=====================


=====================
|    technologies   |
=====================
|id_technologie     |
|name               |
=====================
```

In each table I have these
[records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcWQH.png)

```
employe
=============================
|id_employe|name  |id_skill |
=============================
|1         |jhon  |1        |
|2         |tom   |2        |

skill
=============================
|id_skill  | id_technologie  |
=============================
|1         |          1      |
|1         |          2      |
|2         |          1      |
|2         |          4      |


technologies
============================
|id_technologie| name      |
============================
|1             |  PHP      |
|2             |  Java     |
|3             |  Python   |
|4             |  C        |
```

I want to get a result like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd0dY.png)

```
=============================================
id_employe| name |  id_skill|   name  | name
=============================================
1         | jhon |     1    |    PHP  | Java
```

I tried to do this but the result is not what I expected

```
function listar(){
    $users = DB::table('employe')
        ->join('skills', 'skills.id_skill', '=', 'employe.id_skill')
        ->join('technologies', 'technologies.id_technologie', '=', 'skills.id_technologie')
        ->where('skills.id_skill', '=', 1)
        ->get();
    return response()->json($users,200);
}
```

---

Comment: Please try improving your question by adding images inline.

Comment: I need al leat 10 repututation

Comment: If you can't do that, try to improve your question in some other way.

Comment: Then be creative and post the structure and data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Original:

Are you sure you entered the correct columns?
What I see in your picture is `id_skills` and `id_technologie`.

```
DB::table('employe')
->join('skills', 'skills.id_skills', '=', 'employe.id_skills')
->join('technologies', 'technologies.id_technologie', '=', 'skills.id_technologie')
->where('skills.id_skills', 1)
->get();
```

New:

You want 2 results in 1 row.
And by 1 Query SQL.
You don't know how many `technologie` one `skills` related.

The way I think to resolve is select `skills` first.

Then find `technologie` and you can named as `Name1`,`Name2` etc.

Forgive me poor English.

Comment: Or you can use `Eloquent: Relationships`